# Repetitive Grok Pattern

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse the following web server log into certain fields

> /BluePortServlets/LoadService/servicepath/test1/test2/test3?serviceId=4403&categoryId=1&t=0.13146932582447225

My pattern is the following

> /%{WORD:PATH}/%{WORD:PATH}/%{WORD:PATH} .....

My problem is that since the size and the levels of the path are not fixed i want to have something like a **Kleene Star** format on top of the pattern. But somehow the Grok Debugger doesn't compile it. Like this i will be able to parse paths with unknown size.

Something like this

> [%{WORD:PATH}/]*

The desired result would be

> BluePortServlets
>   LoadService
>   servicepath
>   test1
>   ..
>   testN

Thank you in advance

Comment: Like `%{WORD:HTTP} /%{WORD:PATH}(?:/%{WORD:PATH})*`?

Comment: Yes mate, i am trying to check what u sent me but it gives me null after the BluePortServlets. But its definitely something like that

Comment: I get `{
  "HTTP": [
    [
      "GET"
    ]
  ],
  "PATH": [
    [
      "BluePortServlets",
      "servicepath"
    ]
  ]
}` with my above suggestion. What results do you expect?

Comment: You will not be able to keep all the captures that way, you will only have the last captured text. It is how Oniguruma/PCRE and most other regexps work. You should know how many subparts there are in the URL beforehand, and/or use optional groups. Try `%{WORD:HTTP} /(?<FIRST>[^/?]*)(?:/(?<BLOCK1>[^/?]*))?(?:/(?<BLOCK2>[^/?]*))?(?:/(?<BLOCK3>[^/?]*))?(?:/(?<BLOCK4>[^/?]*))?`. This does not support query string though, no idea if you need it.

Comment: I need to have more than the last captured text, that is my problem. I wonder why the Kleene star cant do the job there. Because the very thing on the regular expressions is that you define a pattern regardless of the size.

Comment: It's not clear what the desired end result is. Given the URL path above, what part do you want to extract into a field?

Comment: But capturing just does not work the way you expect. The answer then will sound as "No, you cannot use capturing to get an unspecified number of URL subparts".